# Restricting user Input to values within array

Tags: javascript, css, input

Is there a JS method (or CSS) for restricting User input to values within an array? My goal is to create an app which uses the Giphy API ( and Ajax call) to display gif countries.

I'm just about done with the code.  However, the last function I want add is to restrict the User input to just country names.

The app currently allows any input and searches for any and every gif within the Giphy library.  That in itself is a cool feature, but the point of the app is to be a geography-related app--not a Giphy spinoff.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail. What kind of input is this? If it's a `select`, it would be easy. If it's a text field, it would require more work. Also, when you say "restrict" do you mean restrict from being entered or do you mean validate after the data has been entered?

Comment: It's an Input text field.  By "restrict", I want the User to get an error if they search for a term that doesn't represent an actual country.  I have all the countries names within an array already.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an onblur event for your input, and check to see if the array contains your input value. If it does not, clear the input, and add an Error css class to give the user notification that their input was not valid (red border, red box, alert event, etc)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a fullstack dev student in Week 6 of my program.  I haven't heard of the onblur event yet, but I'll look into it and keep you posted.  Thx again!

Comment: Good luck! Let me know if you need more help. My JS skills are getting rusty and I'd love to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just straight up restrict the input as you don't know what the user will type. Instead, listen for a `onkeyup` or `onblur` event, then you can check to see if the input value is a country. If not, then alert the user in some way.

> **Tip:** Don't clear the input if invalid as users could get frustrated having to type out long country names again and again.
>
> **Note:** The array might not contain all the countries; I just copy pasted it from github for our convenience

---

For my first solution, I will be listening for the `oninput` event, and then checking to see whether the input value is a country. If not, the input's border will turn red and some helper text will appear until the user inputs a country name. If the input is a country name, the border will turn green.

```js
var countrys = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas"
 ,"Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands"
 ,"Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica"
 ,"Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea"
 ,"Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana"
 ,"Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India"
 ,"Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia"
 ,"Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania"
 ,"Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia"
 ,"New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal"
 ,"Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles"
 ,"Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan"
 ,"Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia"
 ,"Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States","United States Minor Outlying Islands","Uruguay"
 ,"Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
var input = document.getElementById("country");
var helperText = document.getElementById("country-helper-text");

input.addEventListener('input', validate);

function validate(e) {
  if (countrys.includes(input.value)) {
    input.style.borderColor = "green";
    helperText.style.display = "none";
  } else { 
    input.style.borderColor = "red";
    helperText.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial
}

*:focus {
  outline: none
}

#country {
  padding:  3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black
}

#country-helper-text {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: -15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Country <input id="country" placeholder="Canada" type="text">
  <p id="country-helper-text">Invalid Country!</p>
</label>
```

---

The second solution I will not show because it will take me quite some time to make the regexp with all the countries. But it uses the `pattern` attribute of the `input` element to validate the contents of the input. Then you could use the `:valid` and `:invalid` css selectors to style the input and show/hide the helper text.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you.  You're absolutely right.  I shouldn't be restricting user input.  Rather, I should be validating or invalidating with alerts.  This is better logic and I appreciate your solutions.  I already turned in my project but I plan to modify this particular part of the code to enhance the UX.

Comment: @juanCodeAtATime Glad to hear it helped you!

Answer (score -1):

> By "restrict", I want the User to get an error if they search for a
>   term that doesn't represent an actual country. I have all the
>   countries names within an array already.

That being the case, you really don't want restriction (to prevent input), you want validation (to check input), which can be done with the `change` event of the `input`, which triggers when the field loses focus and the value in the input has been modified. From there, you'd simply use the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) array method to check the array for the value of the input. If it's found, the return value will be >=0, if not, it will be -1.

Here's an example:

```js
let values = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "teal"];

let input = document.querySelector("input");

// Set up a change event callback for the input
input.addEventListener("change", validate);

function validate(){
  // Check the lower case version of the input against the lower case values in the array
  if(values.indexOf(input.value.toLowerCase()) === -1){
    alert(input.value + " is invalid!");
    input.classList.add("invalid");  // Attachh the invalid class
  } else {
    input.classList.remove("invalid");  // Remove the invalid class
  }
}
```

```css
.invalid { border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
Enter a color and then hit TAB: <input>
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott!  I believe you're right. It sounds like I don't want to restrict, but instead, validate User input.  Your answer is super helpful .

Comment: @juanCodeAtATime You're welcome. Please consider marking my answer as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer. Good luck!